# run bash script from another script and redirect its output

Tags: bash, scripts, source, redirect

Hi everyone I have to do a program.. I'll be really concise to explain it... And hat I've already done and what i have to do...

Simply, I have to do a "simulator" in Bash that run exercises of students and check if they are correct... for each exercise I have to calculate a score and say if student has passed the exam or not...

I've done almost everything... I think I miss just some line of code to write.. but I think they are the most important too... :(

My script is TEST.SH and i must run the exercise of the student.. the exercise is a script ELABORATO.SH... 
Now, I can have some scenarios:

1. ELABORATO.SH await in input as parameter some values;
2. ELABORATO.SH await in input from stdin, from keyboard;
3. ELABORATO.SH write output in a file/fifo/etc.. ;

---

1. First one point it's really simple to resolve... infact from my TEST.SH I call `ELABORATO.SH` in this way:

   ```
   . ELABORATO.SH param1 param2 param3;
   ```

   Second and third It's more complex to me..
2. I have to read from a file a string (and it's ok) and pass this string to `ELABORATO.SH` as the string was from stdin.
3. I have to create a file with the output of `ELABORATO.SH`... so for example, if `ELABORATO.SH` produce a file (I don’t know the name of the output file) I have to produce a file too, in another directory... How can I do?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds suspiciously like a homework assignment*, but here we go.

1. Why would you source the `ELABORATO.SH` script? If you do and it has an `exit` statement or errors out, your `TEST.SH` does the same. I don't think that's what you want. I would just run the script:

   ```
   bash ELABORATO.SH param1 param2
   ```
2. Did you think about redirecting its input?

   ```
   bash ELABORATO.SH param1 param2 < INPUT_FILE
   ```
3. To capture the output of `ELABORATO.SH`, well, doesn't redirection just seem to be *made* for that?

   ```
   bash ELABORATO.SH param1 param2 < INPUT_FILE > OUTPUT_FILE
   ```

Finding out which files `ELABORATO.SH` writes is non-trivial. (Sideline: if you don't know its output files, then how could they be relevant to computing the score of `ELABORATO.SH`? Why bother to even move them around?)

Anyway, here we go. The following pipeline lists the files created by `ELABORATO.SH`:

```
strace bash ELABORATO.SH params < INPUT_FILE 2>&1 > OUTPUT_FILE \
    | grep '^open(.*O_CREAT' | cut -d\" -f 2
```

Then to move them elsewhere you could do:

```
for f in $(
    strace bash ELABORATO.SH params < INPUT_FILE 2>&1 > OUTPUT_FILE 
       | grep '^open(.*O_CREAT' | cut -d\" -f 2) 
do
    mv "$f" /path/to/elsewhere
done
```

*) Please recommend the friendly people at AskUbuntu to your supervisor.

Comment: Hi... thank you for your answer.. Yes.. It's an homework.. but I really do not understand your note (*)...

Comment: So..

1. Thank you.. you are right.. so I was wrong how I was running the script...

2. I mean to take the input from a file instead of the stdin/keyboard, even if the script is conceived to wait for an input from user

3. I was thinking right that solution my only doubt was "what happen if ELABORATO.SH create a file? Can I redirect the content of that output file in another file?"

Comment: I cannot know which file produce because the ELABORATO.SH is the exercise written from different students.. so one student could generate the output in a file called just "output", another student could write the result in a file called "out" and so on... I hope I have been clear...
However, I can consider to find all file create by ELABORATO.SH and move in another location...

Comment: No... something goes wrong... I'm try to run this command `$(strace bash "$assessment_tests/elaborato.sh" $parameters < "$assessment_template_dir/stdin" > "$testdir/stdout" 2> "$testdir/stderr" 2>&1 > | grep '^open(.*O_CREAT' | cut -d\" -f 2)`.. I need to redirect stderr to my stderr file and stdout to my stdout file and in the end i need to take the file created by elaborato.sh and move it in another folder... 
But I think last step should be not necessary: 
Why the output file created by elaborato.sh is not created inside "$assessment_tests" (the folder where elaborato.sh is)?